# Comment prononcer les nombres à virgule ?

Tags: prononciation, nombres

Comment se prononce (par exemple) le nombre « 3,5 », ou « 3,25 » ?

S'il existe plus d'une prononciation (si l'usage hésite, ou si les prix se prononcent différemment des poids, ou je ne sais quoi), alors je m'intéresse à chacune d'elles, et à savoir choisir entre elles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Il y a effectivement beaucoup de façons d'exprimer ces nombres.

Voici quelques exemples:

```
3,5
```

> Trois virgule cinq
>
> Trois cinq
>
> Trois et demi
>
> Trois euros cinquante
>
> Trois euros et cinquante centimes
>
> Trois virgule cinq kilos
>
> Trois kilos cinq
>
> Trois kilos et demi
>
> Trois kilos cinq cents

On entend aussi parfois [l'anglicisme](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/un-point-sept-17-pour-un-virgule-sept-17) « point » comme par exemple dans les degrés de certaines échelles :

> Trois point cinq sur l'échelle de Richter

ainsi que les fréquences des stations de radio FM qui sont systématiquement citées avec un point décimal :

> À Paris, vous pouvez écouter France Info sur 105.5 (cent cinq point cinq)

```
3,25
```

> Trois virgule vingt-cinq
>
> Trois vingt-cinq
>
> Trois euros [et] vingt-cinq [centimes]
>
> Trois kilos deux cent cinquante

Comment: Très bonne réponse ! Cela dit j'avoue avoir du mal à trouver une situation où j'utiliserais `Trois cinq`.

Comment: C'est possible dans un contexte où la virgule est implicite, par exemple en lisant une suite de nombres décimaux.

Comment: Ouaou, je n'avais pas imaginé qu'il y aurait tant de possibilités. Merci beaucoup !

Comment: trois point cinq

Comment: @Mathieu C'est un anglicisme mais que l'on entend souvent dans, par exemple, « trois point cinq » sur l'échelle de Richter.

Comment: Il me semble aussi dès que le nombre après la virgule devient trop grand (> 999), les français ont tendance à lire la décimale comme un numéro de téléphone voire chiffre par chiffre plutôt que de déchiffrer en millions et milliers. exemple : `3,52455` pourrait se lire `trois virgule cinq deux quatre cinq cinq` ou `3,14159265` deviendrait `trois virgule quatorze quinze quatre-vingt-douze soixante-cinq`. Mais je pense que ces cas sont assez rares pour ne pas être un usage reconnu.

Comment: @JeremyGrand Oui, quand le nombre de chiffres après la virgule est important, il n'y a pas de règle précise. Les chiffres sont très rarement indiqués tous un par un, mais le plus souvent regroupés par paire ou triplet ou toute combinaison facilitant la lecture. Je prononce **π** par exemple, *trois quatorze quinze neuf vingt-six cinquante-trois...*

Comment: @jlliagre Le point n'est pas un anglicisme. Les nombres il y a quelques années seulement étaient ainsi écrits et prononcés officiellement au Québec. La virgule n'est qu'une convention, suivie dans la vaste majorité de la francophonie aujourd'hui, mais le point, en dépit de ceci, fut la réalité très concrète de mes parents lors de leur apprentissage scolaire, et il a par conséquent eu une grande présence dans la vie des gens de ma génération, au point que malgré un système scolaire nous ayant soumis à la virgule, le point est encore très commun aujourd'hui chez ceux de ma génération.

Comment: @Montéedelait Que l'usage du point décimal ait été un temps généralisé n'invalide pas le fait qu'il s'agit quand même d'un anglicisme, c'est à dire ici de l'adoption d'un usage typographique anglais. Un anglicisme officialisé un temps et toujours répandu mais que l'OQLF considère comme tel aujourd'hui. En France, l'utilisation du point décimal est en progression en raison de l'influence de l'anglais.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est correct. J'admets que c'est appelé un anglicisme aujourd'hui. Je ne suis pas d'accord avec la dénomination, mais qui suis-je pour m'opposer au sceau de l'OQLF? Il n'empêche que son usage dans les écoles a donné un statut légal au point décimal pendant longtemps, dont on a éventuellement et a posteriori décrété qu'il était l'effet d'un anglicisme.

Answer (score 1):

Pour compléter la réponse de @jlliagre quand on parle de prix ou de poids il faut ajouter les unités en complément :

> Trois euros cinquante **3€50** ou **3,50€**
>   Trois virgule cinq kilos **3,5 kg**

Answer (score 1):

On a tous appris à l'école que les symboles de ponctuation ne sont pas prononcés en tant que remplacements du mot auquel ils correspondent. Donc, dire « trois virgule cinq kilos » est une aberration. Malheureusement on entend de plus en plus cette prononciation du mot « virgule » pour le symbole la représentant dans les énonciations où elle apparait dans une quantité en chiffres. Dans la lecture, la virgule est ignorée et où elle se trouve on prononce le nom de l'unité correspondante, kilos, euros etc.